# \newcommand doesn't work with \tikzparentnode. Undefined Control Sequence error

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I can't input `\tikzparentnode` command inside `\newcommand`.

It returns `Undefined Control Sequence` error.

This is my command definition:

```
\newcommand{\childstyle}[4]
{
    #1/.style = {fill=#2, grow=down, xshift=#3, anchor=west, text width = #4, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}}
}
```

Utilization in my document:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
.....
\childstyle{L3}{green}{1em}{3cm}
...... % ohter definitions
]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: put the whole thing in `tikzset{#1/.style={....}}`